# Angular Material compatible with other CSS framework

Tags: angular, layout, angular-material, css-frameworks

Can [Angular Material](https://material.angular.io/) be used in conjunction with other popular CSS frameworks like Bootstrap/ PureCSS since I need to layout form controls with some predefined paddings, margins and the like? 
Does the Angular Material provides complete solution to these layouts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes i use Angular material components with bootstrap grid system and it works fine

Answer (score 1):

We are currently using Foundation (https://foundation.zurb.com/) alongside Angular Material, it works wonderfully.  The CSS related to the Material components is self-contained with predefined padding, margin, etc. Angular Material has good documentation for creating your own theme to properly adjust the components to match what your designers have come up with in the proper way.  https://material.angular.io/guide/theming